# How to make a disintegrating meteor?

Tags: animation, mesh, particles

Ok what Ive done so far to make a meteor is this - just a ball at the front of a particle system contained in a weird shape -

[image]

Tried using density vertex groups to clump more particles near the comet head but this looked too clumped. Also, I need to have the head be breaking apart slightly -

[image]

How can I do this properly/with animation?